# Change the styling of a page with an anchor click, without Javascript

Tags: css

Is it possible, without using Javascript, to have an anchor i.e.

```
<a href="#otherlook">
```

to use extra CSS when selected. For example making the text larger, changing colours?

**EDIT**

Please take a look at [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/edheal/GtTrM/). What CSS will achieve the second `p` tag to change upon the anchor being selected?

Comment: not in a crossbrowser-safe way.

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean! Can't you use a class for that anchor?

Comment: I was to implement something like you can select a colour scheme for the complete page by just selecting an # link. @Paulo - please enlighten my for the non cross browser safe way.

Comment: Please clarify your question, there is a lot of confustion between what your title says compared to the post body and your comments.

Comment: If you're talking about styling a page (or part of one) after clicking on an in-page anchor, then you could use the target pseudo class - http://reference.sitepoint.com/css/pseudoclass-target - but as others have said, IE doesn't support it prior to v9.

Comment: Do you mean something like: http://webdesignernotebook.com/examples/target.html ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't include IE6, then yes it can be done in a cross-browser safe way:

```
a[href="#otherlook"] { styles go here }
```

Answer (score 5):

This will do what you want according to your sample link. It uses the `:target` pseudo-element. The `href` must match the `id` of the element you want to style. Put the styles you want to apply to your paragraph into the `p:target` class.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/ThinkingStiff/9JVpZ/

**HTML:**

```html
<a href="#other">Other Look</a>
<p id="keepnormal">Keep this normal</p>
<p id="other">This to change on select Other Look</p>
```

**CSS:**

```css
p:target {
    color: red;
}
```

**Output (before click):**

[image]

**Output (after click):**

[image]

Comment: +1. Never heard of `:target` before. This doesn't work in Internet Explorer 8 and earlier, though, and it's buggy in Safari 2.0 and earlier.

Answer (score 1):

I stand corrected, it *can* be done using CSS. See ThinkingStiff's code.

<strike>No, you can't do it without JavaScript, but it doesn't require much work.</strike>

```
<a href="#otherlook"
   onClick="document.body.className += ' newColorScheme'">Change colors</a>
```

Answer (score 0):

i use this[link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479912/how-to-change-link-color-when-clicked#answer-17480538),

HTML :

```
<a href="#" tabindex="1">Stays colored</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {   
    color: black;   
}
    
a:focus {
    color:yellow;
    background-color: red;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

No, Ed, there is not.

But using jquery it should be pretty straight-forward:

```
<head>
     ...
    <script type="text/javascript" 
        src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js">
    </script>
    ...
</head>
<body>
...
<a href="#otherlook" onclick="$('body').addClass('otherlook'); return false;">
...
</body>
```

Comment: Why would you want to load a huge JavaScript library to perform a single operation that can easily be done without it? (I didn't downvote you)

Comment: @KristianAntonsen: jQuery is quite common, most likely every user has it already cached from google CDN, its size should not matter. Later, if the OP decides to use some of its funcionality, he will not get a mess of jQuery/non-jQuery javascript to mantain. Not using it seems foolish unless under very constrained conditions.

Comment: @PauloScardine Except that the OP explicitly said "without Javascript" in the question.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff: well, there is no practical reason to not do it in javascript with modern libraries; the :target selector is very limited, it may work for the OP very narrow requirement but it was not clear until he edited the question. But I guess anyone can be a jerk and downvote.

Comment: @PauloScardine There are lots of ways to do it. He could use a server side library, too. I have no idea what his requirements are other than "not Javascript". There actually is a very roundabout, almost comical, way to do it without `:target` that I was working on until I saw his latest update.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff: he asked if it was possible, and I said no, presenting the alternative. Indeed it is possible in a very limited way, but I stand by my opinion, there is no practical reason to do this kind of thing without javascript.

Comment: Some people do have Javascript disabled for a whole host of reasons.

Comment: @PauloScardine `:target` is available in the latest version of every browser. It's been available in every browser for a long time, except IE. I don't think its use is that limited.

Comment: @EdHeal: in my webserver logs (100K unique visitors/day), users without javascript are negligible and the ones with javascript disabled don't really care for client dynamic behavior; for these my fallback is using serverside styling: consistent and rich behavior at the expense of more page loads.

Comment: @ThinkingStiff: c'mon, you are limited to change style of **one** tag per anchor, if that is not limited I don't know what is.