# How to change link color when clicked?

Tags: css

`:active` changes the color but only while the user is still holding down the mouse.

for example:

> black (click) > blue (release) > black

Instead, I need:

> black (click) > blue (release) > **blue**

Is there a way to do this with CSS? *Edit: I should mention that I don't want the browser to style visited links, so I can't use `:visited`.*

Comment: I don't want the browser to remember visited links. Is there another way?

Comment: Why do you not want the browser to remember visited links, but change colour after they are clicked? Maybe you could consider setting a flag when a particular link has been clicked, and change link colour depending on that flag...

Comment: because between the split seconds when the next page is loading I want the color to remain blue, but not be blue when the new page is loaded.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You could use a combination of the `tabindex` attribute and `:focus` selector to your anchor elements.

http://jsfiddle.net/dcNzt/

#### HTML

```
<a href="#" tabindex="1">Stays blue</a>
```

#### CSS

```
a {   
    color: black;   
}

a:active {
    color: blue;
}

a[tabindex]:focus {
    color:blue;
    outline: none;
}
```

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong (and 2 years late), but isn't :focus on its own enough to accomplish what the poster is asking for?

Comment: @BevansDesign looks like that's true for most browsers now! I think when I wrote this answer, chrome recently switched from the webkit engine. However, safari still needs the `tabindex` attribute for this to work.

Comment: I have bookmark in my page.  it doesn't work when I click on link that scrolls to a div that matches hashed href

Answer (score 19):

Use :visited to set the color of links that have been visited.

Comment: I don't want the browser to remember visited links, I should have clarified. Is there another way?

Answer (score 4):

http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_link.asp
hope this help ^.^.

set visited/ unvisited color as the same.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
a:link {color:#000000;}    /* unvisited link is black*/
a:visited {color:#000000;} /* visited link is black (reverse the color back to black)*/
a:hover {color:#0000FF;}   /* mouse over link (blue when mouse over)*/
a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* selected link (blue in the split second which you loading the page.)*/
</style>
</head>

<body>
<p><b><a href="http://google.com">This is a link</a></b></p>
<p><b>Note:</b> a:hover MUST come after a:link and a:visited in the CSS 
definition in order to be effective.</p>
<p><b>Note:</b> a:active MUST come after a:hover in the CSS definition in order 
to be effective.</p>
</body>
</html>
```

all of them should have blue color. As you you don't want browser to remember visited link I believe that will a much more complicated answer since U want to change the behavior of how browser should be working.

Comment: There are much better sources then w3schools like mdn https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:visited

Also try to not write like it's a text to your girlfriendzz

Comment: @raam86 : Sry for Wrong posting behavior then.
Btw duno about other fact w3school provided wrong information or not. At least on this one it's correct, simple, could solve the problem ...
have a nice day

Answer (score 1):

In case you are not actually directing users to a new page and just want to change anchor color use javascript:
first you have to Give your links a class like `.changeable`

then you can use **javascript** like this:

```
var links = document.getElementsByClassName('changeable');
function changeColorToRed(e) {
    e.target.style.color = e.target.style.color ? null : 'red';
}
for (var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
    links[i].addEventListener('click', changeColorToRed);
}
```

and the **html**:

```
<a class="changeable">Change me</a>
```

here a live [example](http://jsfiddle.net/wTges/)

Comment: It's directing users to a new page. I just want the link to remain blue until the next page is loaded. There's no pure css way of doing this?

Comment: You want two contrasting things. bitfiddler answer fits you perfectly. If you don't want to use the visited behavior use CSS

Comment: I don't want to style visited links though... because then the link will be forever blue. I only want it to be blue when clicked until the new page loads.

Comment: Yes, but that's why I'm checking if there's a css solution, so I could avoid that.