# How to change CSS link on click of <a> tag?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, anchor

I have been trying for hours to get my anchor tags to work that if clicked, it changes the `href` of a link pointing to a color theme CSS.

Here is what i got and discovered so far.
I have only been trying to change it to the red theme.

**the html** (white spaces removed between list tag to prevent gaps in visuals caused by `inline-block`)

```
<header>
  <ul>
   <li>
    <a id="theme_selector_red" href="" onclick="applyCSS('css/theme_red.css');"></a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a id="theme_selector_green" href=""></a>
   </li>
   <li>
    <a id="theme_selector_blue" href=""></a>
   </li>
  </ul>
 </header>
```

**the link tag**

```
<link id="color_theme" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" href="css/theme_blue.css">
```

**the javascript**
i tried the .attr() in different ways, also tried removing and resetting attributes with no luck. The alert is just to test if clicking is getting to the function, and yes, the website shows the alert every time I click on the link.

```
function applyCSS(css_link){
   $('#color_theme').attr("href", css_link);
   document.getElementById('color_theme').removeAttribute('href');
   document.getElementById('color_theme').setAttribute('href', css_link);
   alert('hey');
};
```

The link tag works, it's just not changing it's `href` when I click on the link. :(

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change onclick to this:

```
onclick="applyCSS('css/theme_red.css'); return false;"
```

Currently, after running applyCSS, it follows the link and refreshes the page. "return false" will prevent that behavior.

Comment: What sorcery is this?? Thanks man. I would love to upvote, but seems I need more reputation to do that.

Answer (score 1):

here is example to show you how to do this its great because even with refresh it stay on the last theme you selected

```
<html>
<head>
<link href="style1.css" media="all" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
<link href="style2.css" media="screen" rel="alternate stylesheet" title="style2" type="text/css" />
<link href="style3.css" media="screen" rel="alternate stylesheet" title="style3" type="text/css" />
<script src="BCo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<ul>
<li>
<a href="javascript:chooseStyle('style1',60)" target="_self" >1</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="javascript:chooseStyle('style2',60)" target="_self" >2</a>
</li>
<li>
<a href="javascript:chooseStyle('style3',60)" target="_self">3</a>
</li>
</ul>
<h1>test</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

and here is the code for the js file BCo.js

```
var manual_or_random="manual" //"manual" or "random"
var randomsetting="3 days" //"eachtime", "sessiononly", or "x days (replace x with desired integer)". Only applicable if mode is random.

//////No need to edit beyond here//////////////

function getCookie(Name) { 
var re=new RegExp(Name+"=[^;]+", "i"); //construct RE to search for target name/value pair
if (document.cookie.match(re)) //if cookie found
return document.cookie.match(re)[0].split("=")[1] //return its value
return null
}

    function setCookie(name, value, days) {
var expireDate = new Date()
//set "expstring" to either future or past date, to set or delete cookie, respectively
var expstring=(typeof days!="undefined")? expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate()+parseInt(days)) : expireDate.setDate(expireDate.getDate()-5)
document.cookie = name+"="+value+"; expires="+expireDate.toGMTString()+"; path=/";
}

function deleteCookie(name){
setCookie(name, "moot")
}


function setStylesheet(title, randomize){ //Main stylesheet switcher function. Second parameter if defined causes a random alternate stylesheet (including none) to be enabled
var i, cacheobj, altsheets=[""]
for(i=0; (cacheobj=document.getElementsByTagName("link")[i]); i++) {
if(cacheobj.getAttribute("rel").toLowerCase()=="alternate stylesheet" && cacheobj.getAttribute("title")) { //if this is an alternate stylesheet with title
cacheobj.disabled = true
altsheets.push(cacheobj) //store reference to alt stylesheets inside array
if(cacheobj.getAttribute("title") == title) //enable alternate stylesheet with title that matches parameter
cacheobj.disabled = false //enable chosen style sheet
}
}
if (typeof randomize!="undefined"){ //if second paramter is defined, randomly enable an alt style sheet (includes non)
var randomnumber=Math.floor(Math.random()*altsheets.length)
altsheets[randomnumber].disabled=false
}
return (typeof randomize!="undefined" && altsheets[randomnumber]!="")? altsheets[randomnumber].getAttribute("title") : "" //if in "random" mode, return "title" of randomly enabled alt stylesheet
}

function chooseStyle(styletitle, days){ //Interface function to switch style sheets plus save "title" attr of selected stylesheet to cookie
if (document.getElementById){
setStylesheet(styletitle)
setCookie("mysheet", styletitle, days)
}
}

function indicateSelected(element){ //Optional function that shows which style sheet is currently selected within group of radio buttons or select menu
if (selectedtitle!=null && (element.type==undefined || element.type=="select-one")){ //if element is a radio button or select menu
var element=(element.type=="select-one") ? element.options : element
for (var i=0; i<element.length; i++){
if (element[i].value==selectedtitle){ //if match found between form element value and cookie value
if (element[i].tagName=="OPTION") //if this is a select menu
element[i].selected=true
else //else if it's a radio button
element[i].checked=true
break
}
}
}
}

if (manual_or_random=="manual"){ //IF MANUAL MODE
var selectedtitle=getCookie("mysheet")
if (document.getElementById && selectedtitle!=null) //load user chosen style sheet from cookie if there is one stored
setStylesheet(selectedtitle)
}
else if (manual_or_random=="random"){ //IF AUTO RANDOM MODE
if (randomsetting=="eachtime")
setStylesheet("", "random")
else if (randomsetting=="sessiononly"){ //if "sessiononly" setting
if (getCookie("mysheet_s")==null) //if "mysheet_s" session cookie is empty
document.cookie="mysheet_s="+setStylesheet("", "random")+"; path=/" //activate random alt stylesheet while remembering its "title" value
else
setStylesheet(getCookie("mysheet_s")) //just activate random alt stylesheet stored in cookie
}
else if (randomsetting.search(/^[1-9]+ days/i)!=-1){ //if "x days" setting
if (getCookie("mysheet_r")==null || parseInt(getCookie("mysheet_r_days"))!=parseInt(randomsetting)){ //if "mysheet_r" cookie is empty or admin has changed number of days to persist in "x days" variable
setCookie("mysheet_r", setStylesheet("", "random"), parseInt(randomsetting)) //activate random alt stylesheet while remembering its "title" value
setCookie("mysheet_r_days", randomsetting, parseInt(randomsetting)) //Also remember the number of days to persist per the "x days" variable
}
else
setStylesheet(getCookie("mysheet_r")) //just activate random alt stylesheet stored in cookie
} 
}
```

also just incase you want to do fast check here is the code for the style1.css and style2.css

style1.css code

```
h1 {
font-family: Tahoma,arial;
font-size: 18px;
font-weight: bold;
line-height: 20px;
color: #1D828C;
}
```

style2.css code

```
h1 {
color: #7c7c7c;
}
```

Comment: sorry i forgot to add the js code added now test and hopfuly it will work as you wanted

Comment: also just incase you want to do fast check here is the code for the style1.css and style2.css

Comment: I'm not trying to go deep into javascript. But I did notice that it does go away after refreshing. Thanks for your answer. This would be great for future reference.

Comment: you are welcome

I checked using Chrom and IE but even after I do refresh or even after i close the browser when i open the page again it have the last style I selected

Answer (score 0):

you can simply use Css, you can find it in this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479912/how-to-change-link-color-when-clicked#answer-17480538),

HTML :

```
<a href="#" tabindex="1">Stays blue</a>
```

CSS:

```
a {   
    color: black;   
}

a:active {
    color: blue;
}

a[tabindex]:focus {
    color:blue;
    outline: none;
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You could try a PHP approach.

```
switch ($theme) {
  case 'red':
  $theme_file = 'red.css';
  break;

  case 'blue':
  $theme_file = 'blue.css';
  break;

  default:
  $theme_file = 'red.css';

}
```

Then with HTML, all you'd need is:

```
<a href="?theme=red">Red</a>
<a href="?theme=blue">Blue</a>
```

If can set cookies with this method so that the theme will be remembered when the user returns, or if you're working with a database you could store it permanently.

Comment: 1. This is not a PHP question. 2. You don't provide a full explanation of where `$theme` comes from (and it **should not** rely on [`register_globals`](http://php.net/manual/en/security.globals.php))