# How can I remove underline and purple text color after the link is visited in html

Tags: html, css, colors, hyperlink, underline

I have a box with an image and some text. I want the whole box to be a link to a new page. When I hover I want the opacity to decrease and the background color to change, as I managed. However, when I go back to the page after visiting the link the text becomes purple and gets an underline.

I tried to use a:visited but it does not work.

I appreciate all the help I can get

```css
.one {
    margin: 10px;
    background-color: rgb(231, 231, 231);
    width: 29%;
    padding: 10px;
    display: inline-flex;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;
    }
.one img {
    margin: 0 15px 0 0;
    object-position: 0% -90px; 
    width: 230px; /* width of container */
    height: 230px; /* height of container */
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 50%;
    }
.one:visited{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: black;    
    }
.one:hover {
    opacity: 90%;
    background-color: rgb(238, 238, 238);
    }
```

```html
    <a href="surf.html" class="one">
        <img src="surf.jpg" alt="">
        <div>
            <h1>Surfing</h1>
            <p>Come and surf in the worlds most beautiful places</p>
        </div>    
    </a>
```

!

Comment: I also tried to change .one:visited to .one a:visited

Comment: I can't reproduce your issue, the color is black and there is no underline.

Comment: Are you looking for something [like this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17479912/how-to-change-link-color-when-clicked)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

did you try this :

```
a {color:#FF0000;}         /* Unvisited link  */
a:visited {color:#00FF00;} /* Visited link    */
a:hover {color:#FF00FF;}   /* Mouse over link */
a:active {color:#0000FF;}  /* Selected link   */
```

Comment: Yes, it still goes purple and underlines when I go back to the main page...